# did two sequential glDrawPixels works for alpha blend?

Tags: opengl, alphablending

I want to blend two tga images with alpha channel assigned. the base image and the foreground image, and the foreground image has just several characters with the alpha set to 255, and the rest alpha value of the foreground image is set to 0. with this foreground image, I can add some characters on the base image (only the characters covers on the base image, the rest of the foreground image is transparent). I use some OpenGL code like this:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
glViewport(0, 0, m_width, m_height);
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glWindowPos3i(0, 0, 0);
// draw the base image to the FBO
glDrawPixels(m_width, m_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_base.imageData);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
glWindowPos3i(0, 0, 0);
// draw the foreground image to blend with the base image
glDrawPixels(m_width, m_height, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_foreground.imageData);
GL_ERROR;
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
```

The problem is that it don't work. the program just render the base image and there is no characters (in the foreground image) on it? I think it should work and I don't know why it didn't. I have test it and there is no `gl_error` happened. Any body can help? The blend function works ok between the background color which `glColor` set and the first `glDrawPixels`. However, it don't work between the first and the second `glDrawPixels`, why?

Comment: Are you you certain your foreground image data has non-zero alpha values in it? glDrawPixels *should* work with blending. Also - if you're concerned about performance you should switch to using textured quads.

Comment: @ananthonline Yes, I am sure. Because if I only render the foreground image (no base image rendered) with the blend function `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` set and set the `glClearColor` to `(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)`, it works, i.e. the characters show on the screen

Comment: I am totally forget to disable the depth test! Add `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` before the code above, the program works.